# Get properties from multilevel objects in matlab in matrix form

Tags: matlab, object, properties

I want to get values from a multilevel object property in the form of a matrix
here in below example

```
clear all
close all
% dummy initialization of myStruct holding desired property 'x' 
for i=1:10
    myStruct(i).userdata.error.x=i;% just to illustrate
end

%% working method
Userdata=[myStruct.userdata];
Error=[Userdata.error];
X=[Error.x]%this is required matrix of all x's
```

is there any better alternative to get it in one step

Answer (score 2):

You could use `arrayfun`, but this is basically just a loop in disguise to reverse your dummy example:

```
X = arrayfun( @(i) myStruct(i).userdata.error.x, 1:numel(myStruct) );
```